# MySQL Need Help reformatting vertical data to horizontal

Tags: mysql, database, concatenation, group-concat, entity-attribute-value

Currently the database looks like this: (product IDs with name value pairs)

id, attribute_name, attribute_value
1, Clockspeed, 1.6Ghz 
1, Screen, 13.3" 
2, Clockspeed, 1.8Ghz 
2, Screen, 15.1"

---

I would like to convert the above data to the following format (separated by product ID, with only one line per id) for migrating to a new platform.

id, Clockspeed, Screen 
1, 1.6Ghz, 13.3" 
2, 1.8Ghz, 15.1"

What is the easiest way to achieve this result? My gut tells me this is going to be done with the concat or group_concat function but I need a point in the right direction, going bald from pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This points out one of the problems with the [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) database design.

There are two methods to use SQL to pivot the attributes into columns, as though you had stored the data in a conventional table:

```
SELECT id, MAX(CASE attribute_name WHEN 'Clockspeed' THEN attribute_value END) AS Clockspeed,
  MAX(CASE attribute_name WHEN 'Screen' THEN attribute_value END) AS Screen
FROM eav_table
GROUP BY id;

SELECT id, c.attribute_value AS Clockspeed, s.attribute_value AS Screen
FROM eav_table AS c
JOIN eav_table AS s USING(id)
WHERE c.attribute_name = 'Clockspeed' AND s.attribute_name = 'Screen'
```

Output of both queries after testing on MySQL 5.6:

```
+------+------------+--------+
| id   | Clockspeed | Screen |
+------+------------+--------+
|    1 | 1.6GHz     | 13.3"  |
|    2 | 1.8GHz     | 15.1"  |
+------+------------+--------+
```

The latter solution requires N-1 joins to output N attributes. It doesn't scale well.

Both of the above solutions require that you write quite a bit of application code to format the SQL query, according to the number of attributes you want to fetch. And that means if the number of attributes varies (which is likely because that's one of the primary advantages of using EAV), then it's possible to fetch too many attributes for the query to have good performance.

Another solution is to forget about pivoting the data using only SQL. Instead, fetch the rows of data base to your application one attribute per row, as they are stored in the database. Then write application code to post-process the results into one object.

Comment: As glorious as this looks, I fear it is a WHOOSH over my head,. I tried to run it for giggles and got a syntax error. (after changing out "eav_table" of course)

Comment: Okay I've tested both queries and fixed a typo.